# Override Django module class method

Tags: python, django

In my Django application I have a module installed via `pip`. I need to override some method located in `site-packages/module/views.py`. I assume, I need to import this module in my custom modules directory, and simply inherit class and override method.

What is the best approach? How can I do it correctly without writing code in `site-packages` directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are after is often referred to as [monkey patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch).

```
import some_module

def my_method(self):
   pass

some_module.SomeClass.a_method = my_method
```

Be careful though depending on the nature of the method and library initialization it may be too late to patch the method. For example if a method that you would like to patch is invoked as the module is loaded you will never be able to patch it before it is called.

Try and patch the class in question as early as possible in your application startup

Comment: Thanks, I will search in this direction! And where can I locate this code? May I create new module say `overrides` in my custom modules directory and write my code in views.py?

Comment: Yes, that is a very clean way to organize it