# Redefine class method for entire project

Tags: python, django

I have a class in my Django project that I want to redefine, without touching the delivered code. The class is this (example):

```
class DjangoAdminClass: 

    def method_a(self, parm1, parm2):
       pass
```

So I want to redefine the method_a for the entire project. How could I do that?

I thought to create a new class:

```
class DjangoAdminClass(DjangoAdminClass):
        def method_a(self, parm1, parm2):
           do_a_cool_stuff
```

But it didnt work.... my method is not called by the code that is using DjangoAdminClass

Comment: If `do_a_cool_stuff` is a function that you are intending to call, then add open and close parenthesis `do_a_cool_stuff()`.  If that is not the thing that 'didnt work' then please provide more information such as error message.

Comment: no, thats not the point... the point is my new implementation of method_a is not being called (regardless of what is inside -- I have added a print('I am here') message to check)

Comment: Are you creating an instance of the class and calling `method_a` from the instance such as: `inst = DjangoAdminClass() inst.method_a('a', 'b')`

Comment: No, I am not.... the default behavior of the Django admin makes all the calls to this class.... I just want to override the default behavior

Comment: Where are you creating this new class? The other parts of your code using the original class are doing so via references other than the name `DjangoAdminClass`.

Comment: For example, if I write `class Foo: pass; Bar = Foo; class Foo: pass;`, then `Bar` and `Foo` refer to different classes, even if `Foo.__name__ == Bar.__name__ == 'Foo'`.

Comment: I am testing a SO solution, think thats the deal (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32530270/override-django-module-class-method)

Comment: @Walucas yes, you want monkey-patching, not inheritance.

Comment: Yes that did the trick! thank you all for the help. Should I delete the question, since its a duplicate?