# Override method of a django builtin Class

Tags: django, overriding

**Abstract of Question:**

I am trying to extend (not replace) some method of any of django's builtin Class in my custom module which would allow to further extend the extended(overridden) method.

Lets say I have two custom modules `mod1` and `mod2`. Want to override same method of some django's class say `get_apps_list` of `AdminSite`, In `mod1` I want to add a line to say hello, in `mod2` it should say hi.

**Desired output:**

1. There should be nothing if none of the modules installed,
2. it should say hi if mod1 installed and hello if mod2
   installed.
3. And hi and hello if both installed

**Question with real example:**

Just for example, I need to modify the implementation of AdminSite.get_app_list like following

From

```
#app['models'].sort(key=lambda x: x['name'])
```

To

```
app['models'] = sort_with_name_length(app['models']) //my own method
```

**Expected/desired approach:** I supposed that it should be achievable by just writing following code in any of my custom module's models.py or sites.py file

```
class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):
    def get_app_list(self, request):
        app_list = super().get_app_list(request)
        for app in app_list:
            #app['models'].sort(key=lambda x: x['name']) 
            app['models'] = sort_with_name_length(app['models']) #an example change I need
        return app_list
```

But what above code does is nothing, its never executed, until I use [Monkey patching guided by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32530270/override-django-module-class-method#answer-32530563).

**What I could achieve**

```
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite

class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):
    def get_app_list(self, request):
        # res = super(MyAdminSite, self).get_app_list(request) //gives following error

        # super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
        # So i have to rewrite complete method again in my module like following

        app_dict = self._build_app_dict(request)
        app_list = sorted(app_dict.values(), key=lambda x: x['name'].lower())
        for app in app_list:
            #app['models'].sort(key=lambda x: x['name'])
            app['models'] = sort_with_name_length(app['models'])
        return app_list
    
AdminSite.get_app_list = MyAdminSite.get_app_list
```

**Problem being faced:** Above does what I need in a totally undesired way. This solution has two problems

1. It will not allow me Multilevel Inheritance (I would not be able to have child and grand child)
2. Its actually even not an overriding, its just a replacement of implementation as it gives error using super

---

**Just for elaboration**, following is an example of similar behavior overriding in odoo, what I want to achieve with django

The exact expected/desired behavior is offered by [odoo](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/reference/http.html?highlight=overriding).

You can see `get_auth_signup_qcontext` method of `auth_oauth`'s main controller

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/auth_oauth/controllers/main.py

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/auth_signup/controllers/main.py

What is does is if `auth_oauth` module is installed anywhere we call `get_auth_signup_qcontext` it would first go to child(auth_oauth)'s `get_auth_signup_qcontext` method which will call super in it. But if `auth_oauth` is not installed anywhere we call `get_auth_signup_qcontext` will directly hit `auth_signup`'s method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite an awkward and hacky but **completely independent/loosely coupled solution** to really override/extend (not replace) a builtin class of django's method is

**Caution** read the complete answer before using code :)

Add following code to models.py of any of your custom (installed) app

```
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite

original_get_app_list = AdminSite.get_app_list


class AdminSiteExtension1(AdminSite):
    def get_app_list(self, request):
        // do something here to manipulate earlier than calling parent
        // Following is the solution line
        app_list = original_get_app_list(self, request)
        for app in app_list:
            app['name'] = app['name'] + '_my_app'
        return app_list


AdminSite.get_app_list = AdminSiteExtension1.get_app_list
```

`AdminSite` is inherited just to make the use of `self`

**Its really loosely coupled** as u need to do nothing anywhere else. Even you can extend it further in any other module and you will not need `AdminSiteExtension1` in that module because the updates to `get_app_list` of original `AdminSite` reside in original method as long as the app having `AdminSiteExtension1` is installed.

**Disclosure**: I am not really a well learned and visionary programmer so I cannot imagine a situation where this solution can cause any problem, so if someone guides, it would be welcome. otherwise the beneficiary has to take care him/herself.

Answer (score 0):

#### Method 1. Use your own admin site's urls

One can simply use their own admin site's urls ([reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#customizing-the-adminsite-class)):

```
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite

class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):
    def get_app_list(self, request):
        app_list = super().get_app_list(request)
        for app in app_list:
            #app['models'].sort(key=lambda x: x['name']) 
            app['models'] = sort_with_name_length(app['models']) #an example change I need
        return app_list


admin_site = MyAdminSite(name='myadmin')
admin_site.register(MyModel) # registering models
```

Then in your urls:

```
from django.urls import path

from myapp.admin import admin_site

urlpatterns = [
    path('myadmin/', admin_site.urls),
]
```

#### Method 2. [Overriding the default admin site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-the-default-admin-site)

You can override the admin site:

In `apps.py`:

```
from django.contrib.admin.apps import AdminConfig

class MyAdminConfig(AdminConfig):
    default_site = 'myproject.admin.MyAdminSite'
```

In `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'myproject.apps.MyAdminConfig',  # replaces 'django.contrib.admin'
    ...
]
```

Comment: Problem is about extending (not replacing) the django's builtin method which later could be extnded further. Can we use `super` to extend the original method's implementation in any of above solutions? If yes please add it.

Comment: @Sami you can use either method 1 (override admin site to create own admin site and use that) or method 2 (overrides the default admin site). As for your previous comment of overriding in two places you would just need to inherit properly.

Comment: Sorry @Abdul Aziz Barkat, I could not really get it. One has to modify each of already built application to add line `admin_site = MyAdminSite()` for registering models of that application. So updated get_app_list could work for those models. If you can explain, please add to answer, also you would be welcome to comment as critic on my hacky solution.

Comment: @Sami in method 1 you just need to import `admin_site` from the file you create it in. I believe method 2 is likely what you want. In method 2 you just have to inherit from `AdminConfig` define `default_site` as a string path to your overriden admin site class and replace this config in `INSTALLED_APPS`. Now you can directly use `from django.contrib import admin` and then `path('admin/', admin.site.urls)` in your urls.